# PTIJ: How could there still be pieces left?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

As we know Moshe, upon coming down the mountain, was shocked at the sight of the jewish people sinning with the golden calf, thus throwing the Luchos - Tablets to the ground, breaking them to bits. These pieces were kept for all eternity within the Aron Kodesh.

Now we find in many places that the Torah refers to the Luchos as עדות - as testaments (Bamidbar 9:15 Rashi, Ibn Ezra Shemos 16:34, etc.)

However why were there still pieces left over? This would seem to be against to the Gemara in Gittin (33a) and many other places in Shas that states: עדות שבטלה מקצתה בטלה כולה - Eidus that is partly destroyed, is completely destroyed.

Thus Why were there still shards left? They should have been destroyed completely!

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have the medrash that the letters detached themselves from the stone and returned to shamaim. As a result, the stones became too heavy and Moshe Rabbeinu threw them down and they shattered. It was the letters that gave the aidus and they were no longer present at all. The stones were merely the medium on which the aidus was written and not the aidus themselves. As a result, they were able to remain as broken pieces.

Answer (score 0):

Either you haven't seen, or you've forgotten about [History of The World Part I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_World,_Part_I#The_Old_Testament). Originally, G-d gave Moses 15 Commandments. One tablet containing 5 Commandments were smashed. The 10 that we have, were not.